# how to test a function inside angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my simple service which handles navigation on my application. 
If user clicks on "next" as per the current state he will be redirected to next page.

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('myAngularmodule')
.service('ButtonBarService',
function ($state, StatesConstants) {

    return {
        next: next
    };

    function next() {
        switch ($state.current.name) {
            case StatesConstants.LICENSE :
                $state.go(StatesConstants.APPLICATIONGROUP);
                break;
            case StatesConstants.APPLICATIONGROUP :
                $state.go(StatesConstants.ANALYSIS);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


});
```

This is my spec file, when i am trying to test it fails

```
'use strict';

describe('ButtonBarService', function () {

beforeEach(module('myAngularmodule'));
var ButtonBarService;

beforeEach(inject(function (_ButtonBarService_) {
    ButtonBarService = _ButtonBarService_;

    spyOn(ButtonBarService, 'next');

}));

describe('next()', function () {

    it('should retrieve the current user', function () {
        expect(ButtonBarService.next).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});

});
```

It fails saying that "Expected spy next to have been called."
There is no backend thingy in this service, I just generalized it to handle buttonbar things.
I am quite new to front-end. I have seen answers which have $http, but was not able to understand.

Comment: you need to check what internal function is doing.You need to add `ButtonBarService.next()` in before each and then check the expectation

Comment: can you answer this in detail. am already spying it. Do I need to do something else ??

Comment: you are testing the wrong things I mean to say, you have to test whether `$state.go(StatesConstants.APPLICATIONGROUP);` in certain condition...the expectation which you are doing should be part of other service or controller

Comment: okay, let me try. Thanks Arpit

Answer (score 0):

Try (ES6 syntax written):

```
spyOn(ButtonBarService, 'next').and.callFake(() => true);
```

Then your expect should work, I think.